# Oracle : ROW_NUMBER 20 times faster than ROWNUM

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

Tables details :

- table1 has 20 millions entries
- table2 has 120 entries.

The target of these requests are to return if yes or no there are exising entries. The number of entries doesn't matter.

Is there someone to explain why

```
SELECT COUNT(rn) count
FROM
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t2.id_field) AS rn
 FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id_table2 = t1.id_table2
 WHERE t2.id_field = 2
)
WHERE rn < 2;
```

is 20 times faster than :

```
SELECT COUNT(rn) count
FROM
(
 SELECT 1 rn
 FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id_table2 = t1.id_table2
 WHERE t2.id_field = 2
)
WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

Comment: Are you aware that those are not equivalent? The second one uses a "random" ordering of the table to assign the row number, whereas the first one uses a defined order. What do the execution plans tell you?

Comment: I suspect that the optimizer is just better at optimizing deterministic queries, but anything without the actual query plan is just speculation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I forgot to notice that the aim of these requests are to return if yes or no there are exising entries. The number of entries doesn't matter.

Comment: @sdespont Then you may be better off using [`EXISTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)...?

Comment: Please add results of [`EXPLAIN PLAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#16889) for both cases.

Comment: @ThinkJet I sware I try but I have got ORA-00905 when I try to display the execution plan...

Comment: There are something wrong with your `explain plan` statement. Please refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#16889) and correct syntax error.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson nice hint, but it takes 8 seconds against 632ms and 65ms of my queries

Comment: Not an answer, just "What if ..." variant: `SELECT /*+ ordered use_nl(t1)*/
   count(1) rn
 FROM
   table2 t2,
   table1 t1
 WHERE
   t2.id_field = 2
   and
   t1.id_table2 = t2.id_table2
   and
   rownum = 1`

Comment: @ThinkJet Thanks for your suggestion, it takes 4 seconds against 632ms and 65ms for my queries in the question

Comment: Hmmm ... Interesting. Awaiting for results of `explain plan` ...

Comment: While awaiting fore more information I can only suppose that `2` in `t2.id_field = 2` is a "magic number". Is that distribution of execution time among query variants remains the same for other keys? E.g. `120` or `55`?

Answer (score 1):

Like said before, ROW_NUMBER() and ROWNUM are not equivalent at all.

The first one is an analytic function which uses a window. Order is specified by order by command.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF51198

```
select
  ename,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by ename ) AS rn 
from emp
where deptno =20;

ENAME              RN
---------- ----------
ADAMS               1
FORD                2
JONES               3
SCOTT               4
SMITH               5


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3145491563

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     5 |    45 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT       |      |     5 |    45 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     5 |    45 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With rownum:

```
select ename, 
  ROWNUM
from emp
where deptno =20;

ENAME          ROWNUM
---------- ----------
SMITH               1
JONES               2
SCOTT               3
ADAMS               4
FORD                5


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1498225739

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     5 |    45 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COUNT             |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     5 |    45 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```